# MySql underscore wildcard optimization

Tags: mysql

Hey, I'm trying to optimize a SELECT char statement in mysql.

I am fully aware that using a **LIKE '%text%'** will NOT be optimizable, but can the underscore wildcard be used in any sort of optimization?

For instance I want something such as:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE '_a_b_'
```

Is there a way to optimize this sort of query if I never use the % wildcard?

Answer (score 4):

No. The only thing you can do in this case - is to create another field, that contains the same data without first letter and find `WHERE col_cut LIKE 'a_b_'`. And maintain it with triggers.